# How to redirect a web service to another web service on another domain?

Tags: php, .htaccess, web-services, redirect, http-redirect

I had a web service on VPS A which ran out of HDD today, and for reasons I couldn't increase its HDD so I moved the web service to VPS B, now the problem is web service URLs are static in application and application host says we can't update your app now , you have to wait 2 days! I have around 100K users and 2 days being down mean death to all my hard work.

The only thing that reached my mind was to somehow redirect the URL and I went with the only way I know it was possible so I tried this 2 sets of rewrite rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^11\.11\.11\.11\$
RewriteRule (.*) mynewdomain.com/v1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^11\.11\.11\.11$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z.]+)?11\.11\.11\.11$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www.mynewdomain.com/v1/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I tried what happen on Chrome, it works but Chrome and firewall keep giving me security error, but on app or REST test apps like postman it won't work.

So it seems access won't work for this.

Update: I'm using PHP Slim as server code (Apache, PHP 7).

Update2:
I set my HTaccess to redirect all requests to index.php
and my index.php

```
$uri=str_replace('/' . '/', '/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$url="http://www.mynewdomain.com/v1".$uri;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') 
{
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
$con = file_get_contents("php://input");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$con);
}
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $server_output;
```

I have yet to fully test it, what do you think about this approach? will it work (just need it to work for 1 or 2 days at most)

Comment: You could proxy from one to the other, search for that? I believe you can do it from htaccess.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9972985/using-proxy-instead-of-redirection-with-htaccess-rewriterule

Comment: @halfer ty for the answer, I found this page https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html - but it complicated stuff for me, I didn't quite get what I need to do, I mostly specialize in PHP code and database not this kind of stuff :(

Comment: Well, you will just have to try things - do you have a non-live environment to experiment in? I would go with the [P] flag first - drop the `R` and put `P` instead. I would guess that you will need `mod_proxy` installed, but if you don't have it available, try without first, or see if the documentation mentions this.

Comment: Ah yes, from the manual: `Use of the [P] flag causes the request to be handled by mod_proxy, and handled via a proxy request`. So in your test env, add `mod_proxy` and try the `P` flag.

Comment: @halfer , it seemd just [p] tag wont solve my problem and you need to install some other thing for it to fully work , check out my update 2 plz ,will it work?

Comment: Why are you asking me: surely you should try it? Do you have a test environment to try it on, as I have already asked? It might work, but your `$_SERVER` contents will contain the wrong IP and domains, but your app may tolerate that. Yes, the `[P]` flag needs `mod_proxy`, as I have already said. It is a single command to install it on a VPS.

Comment: Please do answer all my questions above in detail, but after this situation is resolved, your organisation/service seems to be running a high risk here. You have 100K users but no process for moving servers, or immediate professional support to protect against downtime? That needs to be resolved with some urgency. Relying on volunteers on the internet is not a good idea (and we don't do urgent anyway).